# "@angular/http/index has no exported member of HTTP_PROVIDERS"

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

**Dependencies**

[image]

**main.ts file**

[image]

I want to import `HTTP_PROVIDERS` but is is giving me error that

> "@angular/http/index has no exported member of HTTP_PROVIDERS"

I have attached images of **package.json and main.ts file**.

Answer (score 7):

`HTTP-PROVIDERS` is not used anymore. Import `HttpModule` to your `ngModule` instead and add it to your imports.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpModule,
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [ .. ],
  providers: [ ... ],
})
```

I suggest you always check angular.io page for current info. E.g, [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) usage of Http and everything that's needed is described :)

In the service you want to use http, you import `Http` and inject it in your constructor:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

// ...

constructor(private http: Http) { }
```

Comment: then which provider i should use for HttpServices
@AJT_82

Comment: The HttpModule includes that :) Updated my answer a bit as well. Check the link I provided, it has all the info you need for using Http in your app :)

Answer (score 0):

You main module should import `HttpModule`, which contains the HTTP Provider. That's the most recent way of doing it.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    // ...,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule{
}
```

Comment: then which provider i should use for HttpServices
@mathias247

Answer (score 0):

Just to add.
Its specifically **HttpModule**  and  not HTTPModule or HTTPmodule or anything.

Answer (score 0):

> HttpModule –

```
Http deprecate @angular/http in favour of @angular/common/http.
```

> OLD One : HttpModule imported from –

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

> NEW One: The HttpClientModule imported form -

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

> They both support HTTP calls but HTTP is the older API and will
> eventually be deprecated.
>
> The new HttpClient service is included in the HttpClientModule that
> used to initiate HTTP request and responses in angular apps. The
> HttpClientModule is a replacement of HttpModule.